# How can I speed up a query to Win32_UserAccount filtering by FullName property

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm trying to find a specific user based on the `FullName` property of the user using a simple WMI command in powershell:

`Get-WmiObject win32_useraccount -Filter "fullname='Jack Ryan'"`

There are about 50,000 users and this is taking up to 30 seconds to find all the users based on the `FullName` property.

However when I try to search based on `Name` instead of `FullName` I get a response back in under a second. I don't understand why it's taking so long to lookup by FullName.

How can I speed this up? (Unfortunately I need to filter based on FullName and get all the usernames for those identities)

Comment: Is using [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) not an option? `Get-ADUser -Filter "givenname -eq 'Jack' -and surname -eq 'Ryan'"`, or LDAP `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(GivenName=Jack)(Sn=Ryan))"`

Comment: my understanding is that SOME fields are indexed, but most are not. i suspect you are seeing just exactly that ... the `Name` field is indexed, but the `FullName` field is not. ///// i presume that [somehow] the GWMI call is talking to your AD and not looking at local accounts.

Comment: The name is literally part of the path to the wmi object.

Comment: @Ash these are all local accounts, no AD server running so `Get-ADUser` isn't working. @Lee_Dailey there's no AD server. Is there any way to add FullName to the list of indexed tables? At the end I need to access this via ASP.NET so any other alternative options that can be used to retrieve based on `FullName` which is faster than WMI?

Comment: I doubt it will be any quicker, but the only other ways I can think of are using ADSI or Get-LocalUser (If you have PowerShell 5.1). ADSI example - `$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$($env:COMPUTERNAME)"; $users = $adsi.Children | ? { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' }`. 50,000 local accounts is crazy :) Is Get-WmiObject any quicker if you first filter by Name and then search the fullname property via Where-Object?

Comment: @Ash that's great, ADSI is 50% faster. Is there a way to get a list of members in a local group using ADSI?

Comment: @rboy Posted an example function for how to get group members via ADSI below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting group members via ADSI, as per @rboy comment. Probably easiest to have your own function here if you cannot use [`Get-LocalGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1).

```bsh
function Get-LocalMembers {
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$GroupName
    )
    $ADSI = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('GroupName')) {
        $Groups = $ADSI.Children.Find($GroupName,'Group')
    }
    else {
        $Groups = $ADSI.Children | Where-Object { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'Group' }
    }

    Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Group = $($Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
            Members = $(
                $Group.Invoke('members') | ForEach-Object { 
                    $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name",'GetProperty',$null,$_,$null)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```bsh
Get-LocalMembers                            # Get members of all groups
Get-LocalMembers -GroupName Administrators  # Get members of specified group
```

#### EDIT

Getting both Name and FullName properties. I'm not sure really how much more we could do with ADSI in PowerShell here. I've never really explored it any further than user objects and group/member lists.

```bsh
function Get-LocalMembers {
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$GroupName
    )
    $ADSI = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('GroupName')) {
        $Groups = $ADSI.Children.Find($GroupName,'Group')
    }
    else {
        $Groups = $ADSI.Children | Where-Object { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'Group' }
    }

    Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Group = $($Group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
            Members = $(
                $Group.Invoke('members') | ForEach-Object { 
                    [PSCustomObject] @{
                        Name = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name",'GetProperty',$null,$_,$null)
                        FullName = $(
                            # A Group can be a member of a group and doesn't have a 'FullName property'
                            Try {
                                $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Fullname",'GetProperty',$null,$_,$null)
                            }
                            Catch {
                                "Group"
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

> Disclaimer: I'm running this on a local, non-domain joined laptop none of my accounts have the Fullname property populated.

Comment: This is great. It’s improved the performance by 50%. Im porting this to C#. Do you know if there’s a way to tell it not to enumerate all the properties for each member when invoking members or getting the info? That’s what’s slowing it down. I just need to get only the name and fullname properties.

Comment: @rboy, glad it's working better. I'm not sure. `GetProperty` is only pulling one value, we'd have to run it twice to get Name and Fullname. Updated the example above. Performance still looks okay.